# Conditionally overwrite values in series using a for loop and if statement

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I ran a Logit model using `stats.models` and declared a series with predicted values:

```
M1 = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train)
M1_results = M1.fit()
y_pred = M1_results.predict(X_train)  # This returns a series
```

`y_pred` is a series with values between 0 and 1. I want to overwrite its values conditionally by comparing them to an arbitrary cutoff.

Basically, if the i-*th* element of `M1_pred <= 0.7`, overwrite with `0`. Otherwise, overwrite with `1`.

I tried combining a `for` and an `if` loop together:

```
for i in y_pred:
    if i <= 0.7:
        i = 0
    else:
        i = 1
```

How come this didn't overwrite any of the values in `y_pred`?

I had to resort to slicing (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596521/pandas-overwrite-values-in-column-selectively-based-on-condition-from-another-co)):

```
y_pred[y_pred <= 0.7] = 0
y_pred[y_pred >  0.7] = 1
```

This will be inconvenient when I move onto multiclass models. How can I achieve the same result using `for` and `if` notation?

PS: Excuse my ignorance. I recently moved from R to Python and everything is really confusing.

Comment: `for i, item in enumerate(y_pred):` and then `y_pred[i] = 0`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I don't understand the syntax. Could you expand please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why what you are trying to do doesn't work is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290762/cant-modify-list-elements-in-a-loop-python). Basically you can't modify the element you are looping over.

What you can do to stick to `for` and `if` statements is the following:

```py
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    if y_pred[i] <= 0.7:
        y_pred[i] = 0
    else:
        y_pred[i] = 1
```

However I don't understand why you couldn't stick to slicing even in the multi-class case. But I guess this is for another question.

Answer (score 1):

If `y_pred` is an instance of list you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to iterate over list with indexes. This will give you a possibility to set value of item by it's index in list.

**Code:**

```
for i, item in enumerate(y_pred):
    if item <= 0.7:
        y_pred[i] = 0
    else:
        y_pred[i] = 1
```

Or you can use this one-liner:

```
y_pred = [0 if item <= 0.7 else 1 for item in y_pred]
```

Or even easier:

```
y_pred = [int(item > 0.7) for item in y_pred]
```